# Eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix and orthogonality

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Given a full rank symmetric matrix $A_{p\times p}$ we can build a matrix $U=[u_1,...,u_p]$ where $u_i$ is the eigenvector associated to the $i^{th}$ largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Assuming that eigenvectors have unit norm it is easy to prove that $U'U=I_p$ (eigenvectors are orthogonal). I am wondering if somebody knows under which conditions it is also true that $UU'=I_p$

Comment: always............................

Comment: If $U'U=I_p$ the eigenvectors are even orthonormal, as you've additionally assumed that they have unit norm.

Comment: @WillJagy I don't get why..

Comment: @zzuussee Yes, they are orthonormal but $UU'$ is not the same as $U'U$....

Comment: $U'U = I$ implies that $U$ is injective. So, $U$ is invertible and $U^{-1} = U'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ U' U = I$$
$$ U (U'U) = UI = U $$
associativity
$$  (UU') U = U $$
cancel by multiplying on the right by the right inverse of $U$
$$ UU' = I $$

Comment: How do you know there is a right inverse?

Comment: @amsmath I do not know what would satisfy this OP. One can, for example, multiply on the right so as to bring about elementary column operations, eventually taking $U$ to reduced column echelon form, which will be the identity matrix as $U$ is full rank

Comment: @WillJagy Is it enough saying that since $U$ has a left inverse and $U$ has full rank then the left inverse and the right inverse have to be the same?

Comment: @WillJagy The key here is that column rank = row rank. And since $U$ is quadratic, its column rank is $p$. Hence, it has a right inverse.